# .net webforms - two different URLs but pointing to one file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I do not know how to call this properly, but I need to have application, for example, with two different URLs:
`www.myapp.com/page.aspx` and  `www.myapp.com/org/1/page.aspx`, but both URLs should point to the same page.aspx file on root.

So, this url `www.myapp.com/org/1/page.aspx` is just some kind of "alias". The very same functionality is necessary for every single file, except, Login.aspx file. For this file, second URL `www.myapp.com/org/1/login.aspx` points to Login.aspx fiel that is in Org/1 folder.
The number of "organisations" (for instance, org/1) is not limited. And other URLS could be in form `/org/2` or `org/10`.

So, this is something related to rewriting urls or something else?

P.S. I am moving application from old to new hosting server. And this stopped working. I cannot understand why it worked before.

Answer (score 0):

On your old server you probably had URL rewriting setup in IIS please see the below link for how to configure.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module